# Загрузка больших файлов. Больше 100 МБ.

Tags: php

Обрывается соединение, без каких либо ошибок..

[image: img]

Вот это настроил, сервер перезагрузил, в `php.ini` проверил значения.

Что еще нужно?

---

**Появилась еще одна проблема.**

Загружаю файл примерно 100мб - сервер возвращает необходимый ответ, но при этом $_FILES пуст.

Файлы до 5 мб залетаеют без проблем.

**php.ini** настроил, nginx тоже. Логи пустые что-то.
**Куда копать?**

Comment: Проверьте логи сервера, там 100% должно быть сообщение.

Comment: Где их искать? CentOS 6

Comment: client intended to send too large body

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в nginx.conf в блок 
    http { client_max_body_size 500m; }

Comment: совершенно вопрос не по теме: а как вы уагадли, что у ТС nginx стоит?

Comment: @thunder - экстрасенсорику еще никто не отменял :)

Comment: @alexwindhope где учат-то? :) Очень хочется! :)

Comment: @thunder, http://src.unotes.ru/s/r3o4v7qg9n.png

Answer (score -1):

.htaccess никто не отменял.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value max_execution_time 1000
php_value post_max_size 20M
```